# Raspberry Pi SSH works fine, but console commands not visible on HDMI output

Tags: ssh, hdmi

I have set up my new raspberry pi just fine and I can ssh in with no problems.

Simultaneously, I have hooked up a monitor via an HDMI cable.

But when I SSH in, I can't see my commands on the HDMI monitor, only the computer I am SSH'ing from.  I would love to type in commands and see them reflected on the HDMI monitor.

Thanks!

Comment: This is by design. The login shell you see on the local monitor is not connected to the login via `ssh`. You have to consider that there could be multiple logins via `ssh` at any time - from different users (which should be diplayed on the local display?), from different places (they might not even see the display physically connected to the RPi by HDMI). Long story short: there is no way for the ssh shell to know automatically that you want to see it on the local display too.

Answer (score 2):

## XBMC

#### Using your phone or tablet

If you have an iOS or Android device you can download an app to control XBMC. I personally like Yatse over the official app on Android.

#### Using a web browser

To enable the remote control navigate to **System → Settings → Services → Webserver** and enable **Allow control of XBMC via HTTP** Make note of the port it enables, the username and password. You should then be able to enter the Ipaddress and port number (separated by a colon) of the XBMC (i.e. 192.168.1,120:8080) into a browser window of another computer.

more details can be found [here](http://choorucode.com/2012/08/09/how-to-control-raspbmc-from-a-browser-of-another-computer/).

#### Using SSH or to control XBMC from the command line

You can use xbmc-send. This may not be installed, but can be installed with this command

`sudo apt-get install xbmc-eventclients-xbmc-send`

A list of the supported functions can be found [here](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=List_of_Built_In_Functions)

## For Raspbian

That is how SSH is designed to work, but after a little searching and testing the following does what you want.

After SSHing into the remote machine type  the following in the terminal:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Then launch the program you want to display on the remote monitor, for example

`midori "www.google.com"`

or

`lxterminal`

more details available [here](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Start-a-GUI-Application-on-a-Remote-Computer-using-SSH).

***Note** the instructions above for Raspbian will likely work on Arch as well though I have not tested it.*

Comment: I guess you'll have to explain that a little further. Say if xmbc is running and you login by ssh, do the `export display=:0` and run a program, you'll just get `Error: can't open display`.

Comment: @Ghanima I have updated my answer to include XBMC.

Comment: Concerning my answer: while it offers no "solution" to the task addressed in the question it still provides information as to "why" it behaves the way it does. Whether this is "useful" information or not is obviously debatable. Concerning my comment about XBMC: It was not meant to be a new question, merely stating that your answer (pre-edit) would lead to that result. Kind regards, G.

Comment: @Ghanima feel free to add the explanation as a comment to the question.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work.
I type:
 - export DISPLAY=:0
 - lxterminal
 Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Whatever export DISPLAY=: combination I do, I have never gotten the monitor to mirror what I do via SSH.  Please help!

Comment: @Barisser What distro are you using? Is the pi only running the command line or in the graphical GUI? You may also want to try DISPLAY=:0.0. It also might help you get the best solution of what and why you are trying to do this specifically.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. The login shell you see on the local monitor is not connected to the login via `ssh`. You have to consider that there could be multiple logins via `ssh` at any time - from different users (which should be diplayed on the local display?), from different places (they might not even see the display physically connected to the RPi by HDMI). Long story short: there is no way for the ssh shell to know automatically that you want to see it on the local display too. Workarounds are already given by Steve Robillards answer.